# How to update "sub-fields" from a string field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a database imported into MySQL from a QuickBooks file. Due to the design of the QB database, I have a field that looks like this, but with different fields:

```
First Name: Sammi
Last Name: Fernandez
DOB: 1997
Hair: Black
```

in a single field. The task is, to separate those into the sub-fields, and `UPDATE` the table to place each one in its own column.

The `SELECT` statement works great:

```
SELECT
    TRIM(
        SUBSTR(description,
            LOCATE("First Name:", description) + LENGTH("First Name:"),
            LOCATE("Last Name:", description) - (LOCATE("First Name:", description) + LENGTH("First Name:"))))
        AS FirstName,
    ...
    FROM [table];
```

but when I try to `UPDATE` the table,

```
UPDATE [table] SET FirstName =
    TRIM(
        SUBSTR(description,
            LOCATE("First Name:", description) + LENGTH("First Name:"),
            LOCATE("Last Name:", description) - (LOCATE("First Name:", description) + LENGTH("First Name:")))),
    ...
WHERE 1;
```

I get something along the lines of

```
0 rows affected
```

which means it's not really setting anything right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is not updating anything. The `WHERE 1` on your update is preventing it from matching any rows, so none are updated. Remove this and it should update the `FirstName` field for ***all*** records in the table - use a `WHERE` if you only want to update *some* of the rows.

Comment: Well... I was under the impression that `WHERE 1` will match everything, because `1` evaluates to true. That worked perfectly. Thanks ^^